# Incorrect behavior of NSNumberFormatter for iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

The below code outputs the correct value till iOS 7

```
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"0.000%;0.000%;-0.000%"];
    NSString *str = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@0.55368];
```

It outputs `str` as **55.368%**

But in iOS 8 it outputs `str` as **1**.

I don't see any deprecation or any API change in Apple's documentation of NSNumberFormatter. Is it a serious bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on iOS7 & iOS8:

```
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle;
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Evol, I run in the same issue 2 weeks ago, then I realized it was just a matter of adding

```
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

That should work for you. Let me know.

Updated:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];

//[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"0.000%;0.000%;-0.000%"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[numberFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:3];
NSString *str = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@0.55368];
```

Comment: But this does not solves my problem. I am expecting a format of percentage with 3 decimal places. The API you have suggested is returning 0.55368

Answer (score 0):

It may be an accident that this worked at all - you should have been using `setFormat` (which is unsupported for `NSNumberFormatters`), which supports the triple specification like that, with the `;` separating the items.

You're supposed to use: `setNegativeFormat`, `setPositiveFormat` with the individual items e.g.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-0.000%"];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"0.000%;0.000%;-0.000%"];
NSString *str = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@0.55368];
```